# how to put localhost website to online so that anyone can access

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am working on **web developing** since a long time but using web hosting providors like **godaddy, hostgator** etc. Now i want to host **website** from my own **computer**. I have configured **xampp** server on my pc but its only for my computer. i want to take it to internet. any idea??????

One more thing is that i have configured my domain name in hosts file and i want to host website on that domain name online so that any one can open my website!

Comment: ok thanks for sending link @Trix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get a Public static IP which must be accessible from outer network. Then You need by a domain name. Then map the Ip to domain name. Once this mapping established, when ever some body try to access the URL(domain), first DNS will be resolved to IP:port then the request will redirect to the IP:port i.e your computer. Once compute is found, using port your web server will be traced which will eventually response to the user request.

Comment: i dont know any thing about that. Will you please tell me step by step or send me the link to url you think will be helpful for me.

Comment: Try this link:http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/hostmyown.html